# How can I reset the default Chakra UI button styles?

Tags: chakra-ui

```
    baseStyle: {
        borderRadius: '6px',
        fontWeight: 700,
        fontSize: '14px',
    },
    variants: {
        solid: (props) => ({
            bg: mode('light', 'dark')(props),
            color: mode('white', 'darkLight')(props),
            _hover: {
                opacity: 0.5,
            },
        }),
    },
};
```

When hovering over the button, the standard Chakra UI hover styles are applied to the opacity, I would like to remove this.

Answer (score 0):

I can solve this by adding property `bg: null`, if you know a better solution let me know